# How to convert csv logs to json using transform lambda in kinesis

Tags: python, json, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have a scenario, I am receiving logs in csv format to kinesis firehose directly and with help of lambda function (python) I need to transform the csv logs format to json format and return the output back to kinesis. Is there any way or script to parse CSV logs(any pattern) to Json format using lambda function(python) in kinesis.

**Edited:**

```
'message': 'starting phase |Mon, 29 May 2023 07:38:27:399|117.0.0.2 |35970 |100986593|dev |absgf |password |0| | |0| | | | | | | |0|1d0ijf9da-9ca4-4c94a5-eandv41b4496 '
```

So far i created script to convert one type of csv pattern(above showed) to json. but my requirement is i need to convert csv (any pattern) to json.

For the above csv logs i converted like below json. but it is one pattern. How should we convert to json if i get different patterns of csv log messages.

```
{"event": "starting phase ", "recordtime": "Mon, 29 May 2023 07:38:27:399", "remotehost": "117.0.0.2 ", "remoteport": "35970 ", 
"pid": "100986593", "dbname": "dev ", "username": "absgf ", "authmethod": "password ", "duration": "22478", "sessionid": "9409iu2-243b-40d3-91bb-10oie74 \n"}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What format is the CSV in? What format JSON do you want? Where are the examples of data (in and out) and code that you've tried?

Comment: Hi @DaveyBoy I have edited my question with info.

Comment: If the logs are in CSV format, where is the associated headers for the logs? Don't you have a fixed LogFormat where you know what columns are present at what index?

Comment: If you want to convert __any__ CSV file in __any__ format to a JSON, you're going to need to know the format of the CSV file. Without those the best you can hope for is `{'csv':[e1,e2,e3,...en]}`. There is no _universal_ CSV file format. That's the point of it - it's a freeform data format. We can't be expected to know how one CSV file should be formatted compared to another